# Where is httpd.exe supposed to be?

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-server-2008-r2, httpd

On our server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition.

Apache won't load. I have been chasing this for a few days now; received lots of advice. One specific set of instructions was to see what httpd.exe reports. I tried, but couldn't run httpd.exe from the command line, nor from the Server Manager; errors said that it is not a recognized command.

My suspicion: Somehow, it was deleted/destroyed; quite probably with a lot of other stuff.

Where should it be ? Is there another way to look for it besides Windows explorer and Control-F ? If it exists, how do I find it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most versions of Windows httpd.exe has a default location of:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\bin
```

(Of course swap the **4.2** version number for whichever you may have installed)

Comment: Thanks. Plus 1 for you. This is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition.  I'll edit my post to make it more clear. Thanks for helping me to clarify this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows Server 2008, but I'm guessing Apache uses the same/similar path. Can you confirm whether that exists on your machine?

Comment: You got it. I found it. dtmland for president !